# Within a C# instance method, can 'this' ever be null?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a situation where very rarely a Queue of Objects is dequeuing a null. The only call to Enqueue is within the class itself:

```
m_DeltaQueue.Enqueue(this);
```

Very rarely, a null is dequeued from this queue in the following code (a static method):

```
while (m_DeltaQueue.Count > 0 && index++ < count)
    if ((m = m_DeltaQueue.Dequeue()) != null)
        m.ProcessDelta();
    else if (nullcount++ < 10)
    {
        Core.InvokeBroadcastEvent(AccessLevel.GameMaster, "A Rougue null exception was caught, m_DeltaQueue.Dequeue of a null occurred. Please inform an developer.");
        Console.WriteLine("m_DeltaQueue.Dequeue of a null occurred: m_DeltaQueue is not null. m_DeltaQueue.count:{0}", m_DeltaQueue.Count);
    }
```

This is the error report that was generated:

> [Jan 23 01:53:13]:
>   m_DeltaQueue.Dequeue of a null
>   occurred: m_DeltaQueue is not null.
>   m_DeltaQueue.count:345

I'm very confused as to how a null value could be present in this queue.

As I'm writing this, I'm wondering if this could be a failure of thread synchronization; this is a multi threaded application and It's possible the enqueue or dequeue could be happening simultaneously in another thread.

This is currently under .Net 4.0, but it previously occurred in 3.5/2.0

**Update:**

This is my (hopefully correct) solution to the problem which was made clear though the great answers below as being a synchronization problem.

```
private static object _lock = new object();
private static Queue<Mobile> m_DeltaQueue = new Queue<Mobile>();
```

Enqueue:

```
    lock (_lock)
        m_DeltaQueue.Enqueue(this);
```

Dequeue:

```
       int count = m_DeltaQueue.Count;
       int index = 0;
       if (m_DeltaQueue.Count > 0 && index < count)
           lock (_lock)
               while (m_DeltaQueue.Count > 0 && index++ < count)
                   m_DeltaQueue.Dequeue().ProcessDelta();
```

I'm still trying to get a handle on proper syncronization, so any comments on the correctness of this would be very appreciated. I initially chose to use the queue itself as a syncronization object because it's private, and introduces less clutter into what is already a very large class. Based on John's suggestion I changed this to lock on a new private static object, _lock.

Comment: "I'm wondering if this could be a failure of thread synchronization;" - Yep. 99.99 % guaranteed to be a synchronisation issue (race condition)

Comment: Thanks so much for the great answers. I've been dealing with this issue for months. I guess that's the problem with sync errors in that they don't often present themselves, aren't reproducable, and don't make any sence. In all the time I've spent thinking about this it didn't strike me that it could be threading until i started asking the question.

Comment: @Derrick: what you should just have learned is to not use threads unless you have to, and unless you are at the point where you can just glance at code and see the problems. As soon as you said it was a multi-threaded application, it was _obvious_ that you had a race condition! You should stay away from threads until you understand why this makes perfect sense.

Comment: You should not lock on m_DeltaQueue. Lock on a separate lock object which is "object for locking all the stuff in this class".

Comment: @John: Thanks. I spent some time researching why the new object is preferable in this case and it's still not really clear to me. Is it more an issue of standards, or is there a genuine risk in locking on the private static queue?

Comment: IMO locking on a private member is fine. Apart from the fact that you're using manual locking in the first place. Locking on `m_DeltaQueue` would be a problem if `Queue<T>` used the `lock(this)` anti-pattern.

Comment: @CinC: I appreciate your recommendation on the ConcurrentQueue<T> I did find that most benchmarks show it as being substantially faster. My reservation on using the ConcurentQueue<T> was that in a false result from .TryDeQueue, it did not seem very deterministic as to whether the full queue had been processed. I also read that a TryDequeue may spend up to an entire slice in a SpinWait if if is called when the queue is empty. I see the virtues of the ConcurrentQueue I just shyed away from it due to not having a complete grasp on how the performance might change.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: my concern is that he needs to lock entire operations, not just the queue. I'm concerned about access to `m_DeltaQueue.Count`, for instance. I'd be more comfortable with a lock around a larger amount of code, at least until performance analysis showed me a problem. Less to have to think about.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`this` can never be null, unless the method was called using a `call` instruction in hand-written IL.

However, if you use the same `Queue` instance on multiple threads simultaneously, the queue will become corrupted and lose data.

For example, if two items are added simultaneously to a near-capacity queue, the first item might be added to the array after the second thread resizes it, which will end up copying a `null` to the resized array and adding the first item to the old array.

You should protect your queues with locks or use .Net 4's `ConcurrentQueue<T>`.

Comment: Is there a performance hit in using ConcurrentQueue over locks? ConcurrentQueue seems like the easy way out. Thanks for the great example of how this can happen.

Comment: IIRC even the hand-written IL usually generates a "could destabilise the runtime" error

Comment: My guess it that `ConcurrentQueue` might even be a bit faster than manual locking since it probably uses lock free programming techniques. Your use should probably use the `TryDequeue` method.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - in many situations a lock-free algorithm will out perform a solution involving explicit locking but it's not a given (can anyone find a good ref? I googled but didn't find one). However using a well tested lock-free solution is almost certainly less error prone than coding your own locking around a non-thread safe data structure. And until it's shown that there is a performance issue, one way or another in a given situation, this would always drive my choice.

Comment: IL isn't the only .NET language that can call a method on null - F# can. @GeorgeHawkins if you want a case where lock-based beats lock-free, the time a lock around a Queue for a single thread vs. a ConcurrentQueue. Then consider that lots of times when we have concurrency we don't have heavy concurrency - we've only one lock at a time 99% of the calls but have to protect against the 1%. The fact that locked Queue beats ConcurrentQueue for 1 thread shows it'll out-perform in that low-concurrency case.

Comment: It turns out that `this` can be `null` even without hand-written IL: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17675720/572644

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, if the Queue class you are using is not thread safe, you could be Dequeueing from two threads at the same time. The easiest way to avoid this is by locking your queue when you are dequeueing from it.

```
//declare this object in a globally accessible location
object locker = new object();

lock(locker)
{
    m = mDeltaQueue.Dequeue();
}
```

Comment: @John my bad. I wasn't thinking. I've edited appropriately. The locker object should be visible from all threads that are using the queue.

Comment: I copied the code! I was suprised that lock was being used without an object. I'm reading up now on the proper way to lock the queue. (I'm assuming Enqueue needs to be locked on the same object, and that that object should not be m_DeltaQueue>)

Comment: @Derrick: how long did you have this problem? Any way you can just avoid threads?

Comment: It's happened 4 or 5 times over the past 8 months; only once in the 2.5 months since I added this logging code; previously it was throwing an null-exception. This enqueue should not actually be occurring in another thread so I'm also trying to track down the why/how on what is triggering it. It's likely a property change from another comparatively inactive thread that triggers an Enqueue (likely there is some poor,short-sighted code in there somewhere). The Dequeue thread is very very busy, so as I've been looking into the ConcurrentQueue option, the SpinWait within is a little scary to me.

Comment: @John The locker is declared now.

Comment: @Derrick I apologize for providing an a corrupted code sample. I should have been more thorough.

Comment: @Dark: +1 now. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

`this` can never be null (the CLR will raise an exception if you try to call a method on `null`). It's almost certainly the case that you have a synchronization bug, where two threads are trying to add to the queue simultaneously. Perhaps both threads are incrementing an index into the array and then putting their value into the same location. This means that the first thread is getting its value overwritten.

Either synchronize your access (e.g. with `lock`) or use a `ConcurrentQueue` (in .Net 4).

Comment: That's not quite true.  A `call` (not `callvirt`) instruction doesn't have a null check.  Jon Skeet investigated this.

Answer (score 3):

Queues are not inherently thread safe. This is your issue. Use a mutex/lock/whatever or look for a thread safe-queue.

Answer (score 1):

(Slightly off-topic and a highly unlikely possibility; have made this community wiki. The real question has already been resolved; this is mainly related to the title of the question.)

In theory, if your code `m_DeltaQueue.Enqueue(this)` resulted in the invocation of  an implicit conversion operator on the argument, that could indeed result in a null-reference being passed to the method.

```
class Foo
{
    public static implicit operator string(Foo foo)
    {
        return null;
    }

    void InstanceMethod()
    {
        string @this = this;

        if (@this == null)
            Console.WriteLine("Appears like 'this' is null.");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        new Foo().InstanceMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is an interesting trick; I think it's a good note to have here in the context of the original question. Thanks.

Comment: Technically `this` isn't null in this case, you've just created a new variable based on `this` that happens to be null.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create a delegate that calls an instance method on a `null` instance using the [`Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type, object, MethodInfo)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74x8f551(v=vs.110).aspx) overload.

The MSDN says (emphasis mine)

> If *firstArgument* is a null reference and *method* is an instance method, the
> result depends on the signatures of the delegate type *type* and of *method*:
>
> - If the signature of *type* explicitly includes the hidden first
>   parameter of *method*, the delegate is said to represent an open
>   instance method. When the delegate is invoked, the first argument in
>   the argument list is passed to the hidden instance parameter of
>   *method*.
> - If the signatures of *method* and *type* match (that is, all
>   parameter types are compatible), then **the delegate is said to be
>   closed over a null reference**. **Invoking the delegate is like calling an
>   instance method on a null instance**, which is not a particularly useful
>   thing to do.