# How to get rid of NullReferenceException error

Tags: c#

I get this error `NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code`. The error occurs on this line

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AboveAircraft"));
```

I tried `if( this != null)` and it still got the error. How do I get rid of it?

The code looks like this:

```
public int AboveAircraft
{
        get { return _above; }
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref _above, value, "AboveAircraft") && _updateModel)
            {
                if (Model.AltitudeBand == null)
                {
                    Model.AltitudeBand = new AltitudeBand();
                }

                if (this != null && AboveAircraft != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AboveAircraft"));
                    if (_above < _below)
                    {
                        BelowAircraft = _above;
                    }
                }

                Model.AltitudeBand .Above = new AltitudeBandLimit() { Unit = AltitudeUnit.Foot, Value = _above };
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: It may be that you're getting the exception not from this code but from code that is bound to these property change events. Do you have any data bindings that refer to your `AboveAircraft` property?

Comment: `this` cannot, by definition, ever be `null` - `this` refers to the current instance of your class... it being `null` would mean there's no instance, so the condition would always evaluate to `true`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055068/within-a-c-sharp-instance-method-can-this-ever-be-null

Comment: Yes, AboveAircraft is bound to a textbox in the xaml file.

Comment: Step through the code in VS line by line and check your objects to see which one is null - it could be *value*.

Comment: @VaibhavDesai IMO we need to know what we're doing(what we write), else better don't do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check if `PropertyChanged` is null:

```
if (PropertyChanged != null)
{
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AboveAircraft"));
}
```

It will only be not null if there is at least one handler registered elsewhere.

Comment: @Janewang Is there `OnPropertyChanged` in the base class? It would be preffered way of invoking event.

Comment: No, it is not in the base class. I will consider to add it in.