# C# properties to handle a null class

Tags: c#, oop, properties, null, getter-setter

I have a node class. Variables of this type may be null, the node class contains a pointer variable to another node. If the node class is null, how do I change the getter to return null when attempting to access the pointer to the next node?
My code:

```
        public class Node
        {
            private T _data;
            private Node _next;

            public T Data 
            {
                get => _data;
                set
                {
                    if (this != null)
                    {
                        _data = value;
                    }
                }
            }
            public Node Next 
            {
                get
                {
                    if (this != null)
                    {
                        return _next;
                    }
                    return null;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (this != null)
                    {
                        _next = value;
                    }
                }
            }

            public Node(T data)
            {
                Data = data;
                Next = null;
            }
        }
```

I tried adding a null check to the getter for the Next property, but it doesn't appear to be working.[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t5Tw.png)

Comment: A quick-fix could be to use that null-conditional operator (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-).  A more readable option might be to let the calling code handle the null-check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is - no, if object is `null` you can't call any properties/methods of it at all and hence no code *in* the method/property will be able to handle such cases.

If you really want similar syntax you can switch to [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) that are static and hence can actually check if value is `null` before the call. Note that it will likely to be very confusing/surprising for readers of the code that calling method on `null` actually succeed.

```
public static Node GetNext(this Node n) => n?.Next;
```

You can also consider if [null object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) coding pattern works for your case.

Notes

- `this != null` is generally pointless check for regular code as this can't be `null` in normal cases (see [Within a C# instance method, can 'this' ever be null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055068/within-a-c-sharp-instance-method-can-this-ever-be-null))
- maybe switching to use null-conditional operator `?` like `node?.Next` directly in the code (instead of extension as suggested above) would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access properties of a null object in c#. Because `myNode` is null when you try to access `myNode.Next`, it can't be accessed at runtime, simply because it doesn't exist.

An analogy I like to use is doors and what's behind them. If an object is created, but all of it's properties are null, it's like walking into a room that's completely empty. If the object is null, it's like the door has been barred shut. You can't access the room, so when I ask you if there's a couch in that room, you don't know because you can't look inside. The only way to look inside an object is to first instantiate it.